# Create an options menu from scratch

Tags: android

I wanted to create an options menu as seen in this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQTZc.png

But the problem is, the **only** way that I found to create this type of menu is by calling  **onCreateContextMenu** method and I don't want it to only appear when user long-press an item.

I want it, for example, to show up when user click a specific button linked to a function.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitly show the option/context menu programmatically by calling `Activity.openOptionsMenu()` / `Activity.openContextMenu(View view)`.

Comment: Thank you ^^ I didn't know that that method existed xD now I search a bit more on how to use that methods and I did it

Comment: @C_Chewbacca Glad it helps. Sometimes it's just you didn't find it. It's always valuable to search among all the methods using keywords. This is quite easier using Android Studio IMHO :D

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a [Dialog Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html). These work just like a Fragment class but can be displayed as a dialog. You can find more on using a Dialog Fragment [in this tutorial](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html) to do whatever you would like

Comment: Yeah.. I'm not looking for that kind of popup actually, only a way to call the same **Options Menu** that its called with the _onCreateContextMenu_ but without calling it. Quick example: you click a button and an **Options Menu** shows up where you can choose a preset, so when a preset is clicked on the **Menu**, you can execute it to fill some fields that were empty.